# "Error：path too long to windows" when training Rasa NLU data

Tags: rasa-nlu, rasa

i just planning to train the NLU data, but whenever the NLU model training completed,there would be an ValueError:path too long to windows.I am not sure the path here refers to what?
by the way,I have lifted the 260-characters limit of the file path, but still have this error.

the error stack are following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "e:\anaconda\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
      "__main__", mod_spec)
 File "e:\anaconda\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 568, in run_until_complete
       return future.result()
 File "e:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\rasa\train.py", line 174, in train_async
       finetuning_epoch_fraction=finetuning_epoch_fraction,
 File "e:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\rasa\train.py", line 305, in _train_async_internal
       finetuning_epoch_fraction=finetuning_epoch_fraction,
  File "e:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\rasa\train.py", line 827, in _train_nlu_with_validated_data
        new_fingerprint = await model.model_fingerprint(file_importer)
File "e:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\rasa\model.py", line 341, in model_fingerprint
      FINGERPRINT_NLU_DATA_KEY: nlu_data.fingerprint(),
File "e:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\rasa\shared\nlu\training_data\training_data.py", line 106, in 
       fingerprint
    self._load_lookup_table(table) for table in self.lookup_tables
  File "e:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\rasa\shared\nlu\training_data\training_data.py", line 106, in 
        <listcomp>
    self._load_lookup_table(table) for table in self.lookup_tables
  File "e:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\rasa\shared\nlu\training_data\training_data.py", line 82, in _load_lookup_table
    if Path(potential_file).is_file():
  File "e:\anaconda\lib\pathlib.py", line 1344, in is_file
    return S_ISREG(self.stat().st_mode)
  File "e:\anaconda\lib\pathlib.py", line 1140, in stat
    return self._accessor.stat(self)
ValueError: stat: path too long for Windows
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the traceback, it looks like it's coming from your lookup tables. Are you loading a file in there? I would check on the length of the filename in your lookup table if so.

Also from the traceback, it looks like you're using Rasa 1.x, and therefore markdown. Rasa 2.x switched to yaml as we saw less errors around issues like this.

Lastly, we're more responsive on [our forum](https://forum.rasa.com/) if you want to post there in the future!